# CoreData: Error - entity is not key value coding-compliant ID

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

i have core data error, when i try save relation between ***Group <<->> Contact***

i fetch one Contact from coredata by *hashUser*, and one Group by *uid*
and try adding relation *to-many* with func

```
// extension CXDMContact
func addGroup(value: CXDMGroup) {
    let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("groups");
    items.addObject(value)
}
```

when i try save it, i get exeption

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  [<CXDMGroup 0x7fb7924aa770> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Group is not key value coding-compliant for the key "id". with userInfo {
    NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = "<CXDMGroup: 0x7fb7924aa770> (entity: Group; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://E66299CB-12A5-4152-8B49-8E9B3B68762F/Group/p3> ; data: {\n    contacts =     (\n        \"0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://E66299CB-12A5-4152-8B49-8E9B3B68762F/Contact/p1>\"\n    );\n    uid = 5;\n})";
    NSUnknownUserInfoKey = id;
}

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CXDMGroup 0x7fb7924aa770> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Group is not key value coding-compliant for the key "id".'
```

but i not have any **ID** field, and if i look in managedObjectContext in the moment - i see

```
(lldb) po managedObjectContext.updatedObjects
▿ 2 elements
  - [0] : <CXDMContact: 0x7fb7927f5270> (entity: Contact; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://E66299CB-12A5-4152-8B49-8E9B3B68762F/Contact/p1> ; data: {
    chatStatus = nil;
    companyId = nil;
    companyName = OWN;
    companySubscription = nil;
    connectedLoads = nil;
    countryCode2 = nil;
    departmentName = nil;
    email = nil;
    firstname = Ownname;
    groups =     (
        "0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://E66299CB-12A5-4152-8B49-8E9B3B68762F/Group/p3>"
    );
    jobTitle = nil;
    lastname = Lastname;
    messages = "<relationship fault: 0x7fb7924a25b0 'messages'>";
    phone1 = nil;
    phone2 = nil;
    serialNumber = nil;
    status = Offline;
    timeZoneName = nil;
    userHash = 1002;
})
  - [1] : <CXDMGroup: 0x7fb7924aa770> (entity: Group; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://E66299CB-12A5-4152-8B49-8E9B3B68762F/Group/p3> ; data: {
    contacts =     (
        "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://E66299CB-12A5-4152-8B49-8E9B3B68762F/Contact/p1>"
    );
    uid = 5;
})

(lldb) po managedObjectContext.insertedObjects
0 elements

(lldb) po managedObjectContext.deletedObjects
0 elements
```

i don't understand where does key "id"?
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue, as the error hints at, has to do with something observing the save of the context.  If you are using a `NSFetchedResultsController` or something else that monitors that event it is *there* that you have the issue.  Perhaps a typo somewhere in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: I have a tree of entities which have parent child relationships. I think this answer addresses the problem I have been running into. I have NSFetchedResultsControllers listening to one of the child entity's attributes. My fix was to move the attribute being searched to the root entity of the entity relation tree. I think this crash happened because of NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(...) which may have had an NSFetchedResultsController listening to the save contexts. This seems like a core data bug but XCode wasn't giving me enough information in crash info so this is purely speculation

Comment: TopGunCoder: If you have a tree of entities that all inherit from one abstract parent entity then you most likely have a performance problem as Core Data is putting all of those entities into a single table in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an occurrence of trying to set or get `id` instead of `uid` somewhere in your controller.